# Requsting issues while using JSON payload

Tags: python, json, google-api, request

I was trying to make a script that gonna help my friend to make her work as a translator much easier, so she'll be make only some conceptual adjustments along with a large amount of mechanical work...
My idea was to take Google Document url as an input (there is only tables with a data in this file, 2nd column needed to be translated, 3d column empty and there is must be a translation) and update it using translator API (in this case Amazon translator). This is my first project tbh and I've never faced with requests before, I made this block according to the example, so it's hard for me to generally recognize what the problem is either it API or my code.

```
import re
import boto3
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


#Function to get the start and end indices of a table
def get_table_indices(table):
    first_cell = table['tableRows'][0]['tableCells'][0]
    last_row = table['tableRows'][-1]
    last_cell = last_row['tableCells'][-1]
    start_index = first_cell['startIndex']
    end_index = last_cell['endIndex']
    return start_index, end_index

# AWS credentials 
aws_access_key_id = '******'
aws_secret_access_key = '******'

# Create a client for the Amazon Translate API
translate = boto3.client('translate',
                         aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                         aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                         region_name='us-east-1') # enter the region where you created your AWS account

# Enter the URL of the Google Doc file here
doc_url = input("Enter the URL of the Google Docs file here: ")

# Set up Google Cloud credentials
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    './service_account_key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
)

# Retrieve the document ID from the URL
doc_id = re.findall('/document/d/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)', doc_url)[0]

service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

try:
    document = service.documents().get(documentId=doc_id).execute()
    tables = [element for element in document.get('body').get('content') if element.get('table')]
    table_index = tables[0].get('startIndex')
    if not document:
        print('The document is empty or does not exist.')
    else:
        print(f'The document "{document["title"]}" has been opened.')
        # Find all tables in the document
        tables = []
        for element in document.get('body', {}).get('content', []):
            if 'table' in element:
                tables.append(element['table'])
        # Ask the user for the target language code
        target_lang_code = input("Enter the target language code: ")            

        for table in tables:
            # Find the second column in the table
            column_index = 1
            rows = table.get('tableRows', [])
            for row in rows:
                cells = row.get('tableCells', [])
                cell = cells[column_index] if len(cells) > column_index else None
                if cell:
                    # Translate the cell text and add it to the third column
                    text = cell.get('content', [{}])[0].get('paragraph', {}).get('elements', [{}])[0].get('textRun', {}).get('content', '')
                    if text:
                        try:
                            response = translate.translate_text(Text=text, SourceLanguageCode='auto', TargetLanguageCode=target_lang_code)
                            translation = response['TranslatedText']
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Error occurred while translating '{text}': {e}")
                            continue
                        if translation:
                            new_cell = {
                                'content': [{'paragraph': {'elements': [{'textRun': {'content': translation}}]}}]}
                            cell = cells[column_index + 1] if len(cells) > column_index + 1 else None
                            if cell:
                                cell['content'] = [new_cell]
                            else:
                                row['tableCells'].append({'content': [new_cell]})
                    cell = cells[column_index + 1] if len(cells) > column_index + 1 else None
                    if cell:
                        cell['content'] = [new_cell]
                    else:
                        row['tableCells'].append({'content': [new_cell]})

            # Get the start and end indices of the table
            start_index, end_index = get_table_indices(table)
            # Update the document with the new cell content
            requests = [
              {
                'updateTableColumnProperties': {
                  'tableStartLocation': {
                    'index': table_index
                  },
                  'columnIndices': [column_index],
                  'columnProperties': {
                    'width': {
                      'magnitude': 200,
                      'unit': 'PT'
                    }
                  },
                  'fields': 'columnProperties.width'
                }
              }
            ]
            try:
                response = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=doc_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
                print('Translation complete.')
                print(response)
            except HttpError as error:
                print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

This is an error that i faced with:
An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/******:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "columnProperties" at 'requests[0].update_table_column_properties': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0].update_table_column_properties', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "columnProperties" at 'requests[0].update_table_column_properties': Cannot find field.'}]}]">

I was thinking that this is a problem with an translation API first so i was trying different once, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Can you link us the relevant documentation of this API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest?hl=ru

Comment: sorry, I should've clarified. By relevant I mean more specific like a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As much as we want to help you, our time is limited and we can't spend hours sifting through your entire code and docs. It would be nice of you to at least attempt to narrow it down for us.